# Merge all objects inside an array that share the same key

Tags: jq

I'm trying to deduplicate all objects inside the array `results` that share the same key `id`, and merge their `path` arrays.

JSON input:

```
[
  {
    "type": "apple",
    "results": [
      {
        "id": "apple1",
        "name": "appleName1",
        "path": "/some/path/a"
      },
      {
        "id": "apple1",
        "name": "appleName1",
        "path": "/some/path/b"
      },
      {
        "id": "apple2",
        "name": "appleName2",
        "path": "/some/path/c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "orange",
    "results": [
      {
        "id": "orange1",
        "name": "orangeName1",
        "path": "/some/path/a"
      },
      {
        "id": "orange1",
        "name": "orangeName1",
        "path": "/some/path/b"
      },
      {
        "id": "orange2",
        "name": "orangeName2",
        "path": "/some/path/c"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "type": "apple",
    "results": [
      {
        "id": "apple1",
        "name": "appleName1",
        "path": [
          "/some/path/a",
          "/some/path/b"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "apple2",
        "name": "appleName2",
        "path": [
          "/some/path/c"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "orange",
    "results": [
      {
        "id": "orange1",
        "name": "orangeName1",
        "path": [
          "/some/path/a",
          "/some/path/b"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "orange2",
        "name": "orangeName2",
        "path": [
          "/some/path/c"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've managed to get an [approximate solution](https://jqplay.org/s/5AR451hYfhj) using:

```
jq '[{type: .[].type, results: .[].results | group_by(.id) | map({id: .[0].id, name: .[0].name, path: (map(.path))})}]'
```

But my solution produces two additional elements that aren't supposed to be there.

I know there are some similar questions already answered but I didn't manage to get them to work with this example. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `group_by` the `.id` field, then for each group take the `first` item and replace its `.path` field with a `map` on the `.path` fields of all group members:

```bash
jq 'map(.results |= (group_by(.id) | map(first + {path: map(.path)})))'
```

```json
[
  {
    "type": "apple",
    "results": [
      {
        "id": "apple1",
        "name": "appleName1",
        "path": [
          "/some/path/a",
          "/some/path/b"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "apple2",
        "name": "appleName2",
        "path": [
          "/some/path/c"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "orange",
    "results": [
      {
        "id": "orange1",
        "name": "orangeName1",
        "path": [
          "/some/path/a",
          "/some/path/b"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "orange2",
        "name": "orangeName2",
        "path": [
          "/some/path/c"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fc1jk-gxXdM)